# iOS 6.1.3 Mobile Safari / UIWebView sends wrong locale region code

Tags: ios, uiwebview, safari, locale

I am quite confused about a behavior which was different in the last iOS release (I tested this and it worked).

Changes you made in "General > International > Region Format" doesn't have any more effect on the Accept Language sent by UIWebView or mobile Safari. For example when I choose "United Kingdom" as the region format, the accept language I expect is

```
en-GB
```

But now it looks like it only sends:

```
en-US
```

Does anybody now more about that? Is it a bug? Or a feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my own work (I currently have this same problem) it doesn't look like Safari reports the correct locale at all. Checking online confirms that all Safari reports "correctly" are language settings:

https://www.quora.com/Mobile-Safari/Is-there-a-way-for-a-web-site-to-detect-an-iOS-users-Region-Format

It seems as if this is a feature, but IMO this is indeed a bug. In one of my currently active projects I want to be able to make an intelligent guess at the right language and location a customer prefers when they first visit my site, but since Safari can't report the correct locale I'm having to resort to using domain names (e.g. .com vs. .ca) and other less elegant options to figure this out. [According to the W3C](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-accept-lang-locales), this would be a valid use of the reported locale as long as the customer is not "handcuffed" to this pre-selected choice.

Please duplicate the feature request I made to Apple for this issue ([rdar://13792294](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=3005401)) and hopefully they will do something about it in a new release.